# Adding [moonlighting] tag: yea or nay?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I've noticed a few questions in Freelancing that ask for advice when doing freelancing work on the side (while working a 9-5 during the day). We've had a bit of a discussion on it in the chat room ([transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8874/conversation/tag-for-moonlighting)), but what are y'alls thoughts about adding a [moonlighting](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moonlighting) tag?

---

#### Proposal:

Add [moonlighting](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moonlighting) to describe questions where the question involves holding a regular job, as well as doing freelance work.

If this proposal is favourably accepted as of March 1st, I will go ahead and start tagging questions as suggested edits.

Comment: In from Twitter: moonlancer

Comment: While I love the pun, I went with the formal dictionary definition. I'll make it a synonym if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Done: [moonlighting](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moonlighting)

---

I'm all for adding a formal definition to this with a tag.

> *moonlighting: verb* `/ˈmuːnlaɪtɪŋ/`
>
> To work at an additional job after one's regular, full-time employment, as at night.
>
> <sub>*(Source: [Collin's English Dictionary Complete & Unabridged 10th Edition <dictionary.reference.com>, accessed 5th March 2014](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/moonlighting))*</sub>

It also seems to be where a large number of people start their freelance careers, so I'd expect to see a fair bit of use out of this.

Comment: I think it's massively helpful and we need to be seen as a site that isn't exclusively for the use of established freelancers, but for anyone who does any freelance work in any capacity

Comment: cc: @levelnis. Hi All, I know the definition includes "especially" in the definition, but something feels a bit underhanded or subversive about that, almost "dirty".  I freelanced on the side for years. My employer didn't really know about it but it wasn't a big secret either. It even came up casually in conversation a few times, yet I was very much a part-time freelancer who was moonlighting. I'm not sure I'd want my questions to have this tag if the definition leaned so heavily towards secrecy. What do y'all think of altering the language from "especially without" to "with or without"?

Comment: @jmort253 i noticed that when i looked up the definition and it definitely feels biased. I'm all for the change.

Comment: @jmort253 - that's a fair point, agreed. I'm a founder of a startup and one of the other partners cannot be seen to have any involvement. If his employer found out they would sack him on the spot, the epitome of "especially"! This isn't always the case though so we shouldn't overly emphasise that point

Comment: @jmort253 https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/tags/moonlighting/info I've made several changes now. Are these satisfactory?

Comment: Nice, @Hiroto. I feel a lot less seedy now. :)  I like how you were able to change the wording and yet *still* cite an official definition of the term out of a dictionary.